# Bad 'ls' Command Behavior In Custom Simple Shell

Tags: c, linux, bash, shell

I am having an issue that is just seeming to slip past my knowledge. I am writing a simple shell to learn some systems programming for an internship coming up with Unisys. In my shell, it seems that all of the commands I am trying are working besides the `ls` and even now discovering the `wc` command. `ls` and `wc` works when I type it by itself, but if I give it arguments, it will fail to work and give me an error saying `No such file or directory`.

here is my code:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sysexits.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define BUF_SIZE 1024
#define DELIMS " -\r\t\n"

/****************************************************************
 *  Capture input from the user. Returns the input from the
 *  standard input file descriptor.
 ***************************************************************/
char * getInput (char **buffer, size_t buflen)
{
    size_t bufsize = BUF_SIZE;
    *buffer = malloc(sizeof(char) * bufsize + 1);   // allocate space for the buffer

    if (!*buffer)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Shell: buffer allocation error\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    printf("$$ ");

    fflush(NULL);

    int bytesRead = getline(&(*buffer), &bufsize, stdin);
    if (bytesRead < 0)
    {
        printf("Getline error\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    return *buffer; // Not capturing return value right now
 }

/****************************************************************
 *  Tokenize the buffer input from stdin
 ***************************************************************/
char ** splitLine(char *line)
{
    int bufsize = BUF_SIZE;
    int pos = 0;
    char **tokens = malloc (sizeof(char) * BUF_SIZE + 1);
    char *token;

    if (!tokens)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Shell: buffer allocation error\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    /* Tokenize the line */
    token = strtok(line, DELIMS);
    while (token != NULL)
    {
        tokens[pos] = token;
        pos++;
        if (pos > bufsize)
        {
            bufsize += BUF_SIZE;
            tokens = realloc(tokens, bufsize * sizeof(char) + 1);
            if (!tokens)
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "Shell: buffer allocation error\n");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
        }
        token = strtok(NULL, DELIMS);   // continue grabbing tokens
    }

    tokens[pos] = NULL;
    return tokens;
}

/****************************************************************
 *  Main function
 ***************************************************************/
int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    char *buf;     // buffer to hold user input from standard input stream.
    pid_t pid;          // Parent id of the current process
    int status;

    /* Loop while the user is getting input */
    while (getInput(&buf, sizeof(buf)))
    {
        char **args = splitLine(buf);
        int i = 0;

        /* Print tokens just to check if we are processing them correctly */
        while (1)
        {
            char *token = args[i++];
            if (token != NULL)
                printf("Token #%d: %s\n", i, token);
            else
                break;
        }

        fflush(NULL);

        /* Fork and execute command in the shell */
        pid = fork();
        switch(pid)
        {
            case -1:
            {
                /* Failed to fork */
                fprintf(stderr, "Shell cannot fork: %s\n", strerror(errno));
                continue;
            }
            case 0:
            {
                /* Child so run the command */
                execvp(args[0], args);        // Should not ever return otherwise there was an error
                fprintf(stderr, "Shell: couldn't execute %s: %s\n   ", buf, strerror(errno));
                exit(EX_DATAERR);
            }
        }

        /* Suspend execution of calling process until receiving a status message from the child process
            or a signal is received. On return of waitpid, status contains the termination
            information about the process that exited. The pid parameter specifies the set of child
            process for which to wait for */
        if ((pid = waitpid(pid, &status, 0) < 0))
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Shell: waitpid error: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        }

        free(args);
    }

    free(buf);

    exit(EX_OK);
}
```

For example, I have tried the following commands with output:

**ls -la** (THE ISSUE)

```
$$ ls -la
Token #1: ls
Token #2: la
ls: la: No such file or directory
$$
```

**wc -l** (THE ISSUE)

```
$$ wc -l
Token #1: wc
Token #2: l
wc: l: open: No such file or directory
```

**ls**

```
$$ ls
Token #1: ls
Makefile    driver      driver.dSYM main.c      main.o
$$
```

**ps -la**

```
$$ ps -la
Token #1: ps
Token #2: la
  UID   PID  PPID CPU PRI NI      VSZ    RSS WCHAN  STAT   TT       TIME COMMAND
    0  2843  2405   0  31  0  2471528      8 -      Us   s000    0:00.08 login 
  501  2845  2843   0  31  0  2463080   1268 -      S    s000    0:01.08 -bash
  501  4549  2845   0  31  0  2454268    716 -      S+   s000    0:00.01 ./driv
    0  4570  4549   0  31  0  2435020    932 -      R+   s000    0:00.00 ps la
$$
```

**which which**

```
$$ which which
Token #1: which
Token #2: which
/usr/bin/which
```

**which -a which**

```
$$ which -a which 
Token #1: which
Token #2: a
Token #3: which
/usr/bin/which
```

and even finally **man getline**

```
GETLINE(3)               BSD Library Functions Manual               GETLINE(3)

NAME
     getdelim, getline -- get a line from a stream

LIBRARY
     Standard C Library (libc, -lc)
.
.
.
```

Can anybody help me point out why I am having this issue?

Comment: Just looking at your output, you're losing the `-` from command line options, so in the first example you're effectively doing an `ls la`, which will give the same error in bash. `ps` works because `ps` takes some options without the `-`.

Comment: And further to what @blm says, you have `#define DELIMS " -\r\t\n"` and you're using that with `strtok()`.  Remove the dash from the delimiter list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Youve added "-" as a word seperator in the DELIMS macro.

Removing it should fix your problem.

As an aside, its probably best to avoid macros where you can do so easily. Here, I would have used a `const char* delims` to store the separators. I usually find it easier to declare a variable close to where its used - I think that makes it easier to spot bugs and read the code.

Comment: OOPS! sorry about that one guys. I am so dumb haha. That fixed the issue. Thank you very much for pointing that out for me. Gosh, sorry to waste your time guys :(